# PowerShell does not show spanish text correctly

Tags: powershell, smtp, office365

I am using PowerShell to send an email from a Windows Server 2008 R2 by scripting in spanish, but the text does not show correctly.

This is mi code:

```
$file = "c:\Contenido-Mail.txt"

if (test-path $file)
{

    $from = "afgarciact@gmail.com"
    $to = "<itmanager@credivalores.com>"
    #Las direcciones del to deben indicarse con signos de mayor que 
    #y menor que.
    $pc = get-content env:computername
    $subject = "Mesaje de prueba del servidor " + $pc
    $smtpserver ="192.168.4.133"


    #Con Out-String formateamos el texto
    $body = Get-Content $file | Out-String


    foreach ($recipient in $to)
    {
        write-host "Enviando mail a $to"
        Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $smtpserver -from $from -to $recipient -subject $subject  -body $body
    }
}
else
{
write-host "Configuración"
}
```

Here is the body:

> Juego de tronos (Game of Thrones en inglés) es una serie de televisión

And here is how it looks like in the Outlook client:

> Juego de tronos (Game of Thrones en ingl?s) es una serie de televisi?n

Do you think I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Try playing with the encoding on the Get-Content command .. maybe add `-Encoding "ISO-8859-1"` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text document is encoded as UTF8, try this:

```
$body = Get-Content $file -encoding UTF8 | Out-String
```

Comment: How do I check if my text document is encoded as UTF8? Try that, but did not work. Thanks!

Comment: You could download a text editor like Notepad++ which would tell you (and let you switch which type).